# Is it possible to use Java enum in ISML expressions

Tags: intershop

I would like to compare an enum in `<isif>` condition, something like:

```
    <isif condition="#benefit:type == BenefitTypeEnum:Discount#">
        <!-- Do discount specific code here -->
    </isif>
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the following is possible to use enums in ISML:

```
    <isif condition="Benefit:Type EQ 'DISCOUNT'">
        <!-- Discount specific code here -->
    </isif>
```

In this example `'DISCOUNT'` is the name of the enum value in Java

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to write a custom ISML function that is capable in handling the enums ordinal values. I haven't done this personally but there is a [cookbook recipe](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2845G8) that explains how to write such functions that are not part of the ISML grammar.